# adding fields of a formset dynamically

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

i have a formset inside my form on django and i need to do a button add to offer to the user the possibility to fill the fields of the formset as many time as he wants. i used a javascript code to do that and i do all the following  steps to link the js file with the project, but when i click on the button nothing happens, i don't know why. please if anyone could help me.

i add staticfiles on my settings

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (BASE_DIR / "static",)
```

part of my html file

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
   <title>ordonnancement </title>
    ...
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="bg-gray-100">
  <form action="/" method="post" class="join-form mt-8 m-auto">
    {% csrf_token %}
     ...
    {% for form_data in formset %}
          <div class="mt-4 w-1/2 mx-1">
            {{ form_data.nom_qualité }}
          </div>
          <div class="mt-4 w-1/2 mx-1">
            {{ form_data.id_qualité }}
          </div>
          <div class="mt-4 w-1/2 mx-1">
            {{ form_data.date_début }}
          </div>
          <div class="mt-4 w-1/2 mx-1">
            {{ form_data.date_fin }}
          </div>
        {% endfor %}
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success add-form-row"
                   id="{{ formset.prefix }}">
                ajouter
        </button>
        {{ formset.management_form }}      
      ...
    </form>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/formset.js' %}">
   </script>
```

js file

```
function updateElementIndex(el, prefix, ndx) {
var id_regex = new RegExp('(' + prefix + '-\\d+-)');
var replacement = prefix + '-' + ndx + '-';
if ($(el).attr("for")) $(el).attr("for", $(el).attr("for").replace(id_regex,
replacement));
if (el.id) el.id = el.id.replace(id_regex, replacement);
if (el.name) el.name = el.name.replace(id_regex, replacement);
}

function addForm(btn, prefix) {
var formCount = parseInt($('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val());
if (formCount < 1000) {
    // Clone a form (without event handlers) from the first form
    var row = $(".item:last").clone(false).get(0);

    // Insert it after the last form
    $(row).removeAttr('id').hide().insertAfter(".item:last").slideDown(300);

    // Remove the bits we don't want in the new row/form
    // e.g. error messages
    $(".errorlist", row).remove();
    $(row).children().removeClass("error");

    // Relabel or rename all the relevant bits
    $(row).find('.formset-field').each(function () {
        updateElementIndex(this, prefix, formCount);
        $(this).val('');
        $(this).removeAttr('value');
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
    });

    // Add an event handler for the delete item/form link
    $(row).find(".delete").click(function () {
        return deleteForm(this, prefix);
    });
    // Update the total form count
    $("#id_" + prefix + "-TOTAL_FORMS").val(formCount + 1);

   } // End if

  return false;
  }
 function deleteForm(btn, prefix) {
  var formCount = parseInt($('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val());
  if (formCount > 1) {
      // Delete the item/form
      var goto_id = $(btn).find('input').val();
      if( goto_id ){
        $.ajax({
            url: "/" + window.location.pathname.split("/")[1] + "/formset-data-delete/"+ goto_id +"/ 
      next="+ window.location.pathname,
            error: function () {
              console.log("error");
            },
            success: function (data) {
              $(btn).parents('.item').remove();                 
            },
            type: 'GET'
        });
      }else{
        $(btn).parents('.item').remove();
      }

      var forms = $('.item'); // Get all the forms
      // Update the total number of forms (1 less than before)
      $('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val(forms.length);
      var i = 0;
      // Go through the forms and set their indices, names and IDs
      for (formCount = forms.length; i < formCount; i++) {
          $(forms.get(i)).find('.formset-field').each(function () {
              updateElementIndex(this, prefix, i);
          });
       }
    } // End if

    return false;
    }
   $("body").on('click', '.remove-form-row',function () {
   deleteForm($(this), String($('.add-form-row').attr('id')));
   });

  $("body").on('click', '.add-form-row',function () {
  return addForm($(this), String($(this).attr('id')));
  });
```

Comment: Your code _seems_ ok. Maybe you can find more information in your browser's javascript console?